# Using MongoDB (in a container?) in Visual Studio Team Services pipelines

Tags: continuous-integration, containers, azure-devops

I have a node.js server that communicates with a MongoDB database. As part of the continuous-integration process I'd like to spin up a MongoDB database and run my tests against the server + DB.

With bitbucket pipelines I can spin up a container that has both node.js and MongoDB. I then run my tests against this setup.

What would be the best way to achieve this with Visual Studio Team Services? Some options that come to mind:

1) Hosted pipelines seem easiest but they don't have MongoDB on them. I could use [Tool Installers](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/process/tasks#tool-installers), but there's no mention of a MongoDB installer, and in fact I don't see any tool installer in my list of available tasks. Also, it is mentioned that there is no admin access to the hosted pipeline machines and I believe MongoDB requires admin access. Lastly, downloading and installing Mongo takes quite a bit of time.

2) Set up my own private pipeline - i.e. a VM with Node + Mongo, and install the pipeline agent on it. Do I have to spin up a dedicate Azure instance for this? Will this instance be torn down and set up again on each test run, or will it remain up between test runs (meaning I have to take extra care to clean it up)?

3) Magically use a container in the pipeline through an option that I haven't yet discovered...?

I'd really like to use a container to run my tests because then I can use the same container locally during the development process, rather than having to maintain multiple environments. Can this be done?

Comment: Can you spin up a MongoDB database via command line or tool?

Comment: @starain-MSFT Not that I know of. I could download the MongoDB installer with a Powershell command line and then silently install it (this is basically what my option (1) was about), but it takes quite a bit of time. Is that the approach you'd recommend?

Comment: I am not familiar with MongoDB, does spin up MongoDB mean setup a database. You can setup MongoDB on your private build agent machine, then use it directly.

Comment: @starain-MSFT See my questions in my option (2) above - does the private build instance recycle every build? I take it there's no way to use containers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So as it turns out, VSTS now has Docker support in its pipeline (when I wrote my question it was in beta and I didn't find it for whatever reason). It can be found at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.docker.

This command allows you to spin up a container of your choice and run a single command on it. If this command is to be synchronously run as part of the pipeline, then `Run in Background` needs to be unchecked (this will be the case for regular build commands, I guess). I ended up pushing a build script into my git repository and running it on a container.

And re. my question in (2) above - machines in private pipelines aren't cleaned up between pipeline runs.